# Python Saltstack: How can I manage a file which is in a git repo?

Tags: python, salt-stack

I have a configuration file, config.py in my git repository. It has dev-specific configuration settings.

I also have that same file as a managed file in salt, which has production-specific configurations.

The configuration directive for that file looks like this:

```
python_config:
  file.managed:
    - name: /opt/github/python_config/config.py
    - source: salt://configs/config.py
    - makedirs: True
```

Because `/opt/github` is a git repository, whenever I try to update that directory, I get an error: "You local changes to python_config/config.py would be overwritten by merge."

Here is what my salt directive for that github repo looks like:

```
code:
    git.latest:
        - name: {{ pillar['git_repo'] }}
        - rev: {{ pillar['git_rev'] }}
        - target: {{ pillar['source_path'] }}
        - force: True
        - require:
            - pkg: app-pkgs
            - file: deploykey
            - file: publickey
            - file: ssh_config
```

This error makes sense - I've checked out the repository, made a change (via my managed file), so *new* changes to that dev-specific config file cause issues.

How can I force salt to perform tasks in a specific order? (eg, issue a `git checkout config.py` before proceeding with with the `git pull`?)

Alternately, is there a better/different way I should manage this prod-vs-dev configuration in salt?

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet here would probably be to use the gitfs backend.

Docs can be found here: http://docs.saltstack.com/topics/tutorials/gitfs.html

This allows you to use git as a backend for your file_roots.

Each git branch and tag becomes a Salt environment, which will map nicely to your production and dev configurations.

This will remove the need for your git.latest state declaration.

```
python_config:
  file.managed:
    - name: /opt/github/python_config/config.py
    - source: salt://configs/config.py
    - makedirs: True
```

Comment: Do you know how to debug gitfs in salt? I am getting it to work, but only with the example tag (salt-base) whenever I use other branch or tag names the files are not found. Salt minion or master logs don't show any errors.

Comment: Usually stopping the minion daemon and running the minion in the terminal will show you relevant errors.  `salt-minion -l debug`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just run the checkout command before you do `git.latest` on `state.highstate`:

1. Add an additional `cmd.run` state
2. Require that state in your `git.latest` state
3. Require the `git.latest` state in your `file.managed` state

Then when you run `state.highstate`, it will run your `git checkout` command, then update your repo to latest, then make sure the file looks like it should.

It's less than ideal in that it will always be reporting that the file has changed in your file.managed state (because you'll check it out every time), but it will accomplish what you set out to do.

If you didn't want to check it out *every* time, you could craft some command to check if there are upstream changes to your git repo, and use the `onlyif` arg to `cmd.run` to only run `git checkout` if you are actually going to pull new changes.  This would make your `state.highstate` output cleaner (in that it will not have changes as often) but is more complex, which is not ideal.

Keep me posted if you'd like further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a git issue, than a salt issue.

Look into using `git stash` (possibly `git stash --keep-index`).
(Then `git stash pop`)

I would only use this on that one config file though, as you can easily run into merge conflicts when doing this on files bound for upstream on a multi user repo.

Comment: Sure. The question is, how can I coerce salt into calling `git stash` *before* it does a `git checkout`?